# Python Tkinter: How to decrease tab space in Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

So I have the following code that creates the GUI in the picture below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
root = tk.Tk()
# Some code

# Creating Master TreeView
treeView = ttk.Treeview(root)
treeView.heading("#0", text="Variables", anchor=tk.W)
treeView.place(relx=0, rely=0.00,relwidth=0.1,relheight=1)
# Some Code

# Creating Folders/Sub Folders
var = treeView.insert("", 0, text=name)
treeView.insert(var, "end", text="Type: "+type)
treeView.insert(var, "end", text="Value: "+str(value))
```

This is what It looks like without being pressed and then pressed
[image] [image]

Is there anyway to decrease the tabspace of the sub folders? Like bring it back to where the black point is?

[image]

For context, this is what the whole gui looks like:
[image]

I have to reserve so much space for the Treeview just to make sure the subfolders appear on the screean, and it takes up way to much space. I tend to find that the treeview uses a lot of unnecessary space when adding subfolders

Answer (score 0):

You can try and constain the tree column:
treeView.column('#0', width=your_width, stretch=False)

Comment: That just limits the column width of the treeview, not the tab spacing of the subfolders